# How to sort unicode characters without using locale?

Tags: unicode

We have an application which will sort the set of strings written in different languages.
The problem is that all of those srtings are located in a same column in a database, and there is no locale specified for those strings.
When I have told my colleagues that it is not possible to sort those strings without using locale information, my colleagues replay me with the question "how the database does the same jobs for us"?
May someone had a same problem and know the solution how to sort strings in unicode without using locale information? And second question is it absolute possible to do?

Comment: Your colleagues seem to assume that the dbase engine doesn't use locale.  It does.  Collation order is an important engine configuration item.  The default system locale if necessary.  Otherwise too vague to give specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your Database will have a default *collation* which will (amongst other things) be used for ordering.

I believe it is actually possible to [specify the collation for ordering during a query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) (although I have no idea what performance hit this would have).